Create SQL with multiple outputs
I got a template
VARIABLE res NUMBER;
BEGIN
    SELECT count(*) into :res FROM DMS.OCR_QUEUE;
END;
/
select 'details:OCR Queue: '||:res from dual;

def warn = 99;
def crit = 999;

select 'perfdata:OcrQueue='||:res||';'||&warn||';'||&crit||';100;' from dual;

SELECT 'exit:'|| CASE WHEN :res > &warn and :res <= &crit THEN 1 WHEN :res > &crit THEN 2 ELSE 0 END FROM dual;

And should create something like that for tables where last_analyzed is older than x months. I don't need perfdata, only details and exit.
I got a SQL that gives me all the information I need but I don't have a clue how get them into details and exit.
SELECT
    OWNER,
    TABLE_NAME,
    LAST_ANALYZED,
    CASE
        WHEN LAST_ANALYZED >= TRUNC(SYSDATE) - INTERVAL '1' MONTH THEN 0
        WHEN LAST_ANALYZED >= TRUNC(SYSDATE) - INTERVAL '2' MONTH AND LAST_ANALYZED < TRUNC(SYSDATE) - INTERVAL '1' MONTH THEN 1
        ELSE 2
    END AS DATE_CATEGORY
FROM
    DBA_TABLES
WHERE
    OWNER IN(SELECT USERNAME FROM DBA_USERS WHERE ORACLE_MAINTAINED = 'N')
AND
    NUM_ROWS > 100
ORDER BY LAST_ANALYZED DESC;

The result should look like this:
detail: ref_contract_details - contracts - 22.03.2024
ref_document_attributes - dms - 13.02.2024
ref_document_types - dms - 12.02.2024
exit:1
So I need all tables with more than 100 entries in the format table_name - owner - last_analyzed
and then one exit statement that checks for the highest number in date_category and displays it.
Example:
last_analyzed less than one month ago - 0
last_analyzed one month or less than two months ago - 1
last_analyzed more than two months ago - 2
So if there is any last_analyzed entry older than two months then exit should be 2. If there are only entris between zero and two months old then 1. And if there are only entries younger than one month then 0.

Just add a dummy column at the front of your SELECT statement, e.g.  'details:' AS class. Make sure to set linesize sufficiently large to avoid wrapping, and then you can grep out the details from the spool/redirect file when you're done.

Please [edit] the question and include the expected output in your question as, at the moment, it is not clear what you are expecting the result to be.

Use PL/SQL, a cursor and EXECUTE IMMEDIATE to loop over each table:
DECLARE
  res  PLS_INTEGER;
  warn CONSTANT PLS_INTEGER := 99;
  crit CONSTANT PLS_INTEGER := 999;
BEGIN
  FOR r IN (
    SELECT OWNER,
           TABLE_NAME,
           LAST_ANALYZED,
           TRUNC(MONTHS_BETWEEN(TRUNC(SYSDATE), LAST_ANALYSED)) AS DATE_CATEGORY
    FROM   DBA_TABLES
    WHERE  OWNER IN( SELECT USERNAME
                     FROM   DBA_USERS
                     WHERE ORACLE_MAINTAINED = 'N' )
    AND    NUM_ROWS > 100
    AND    MONTHS_BETWEEN(TRUNC(SYSDATE), LAST_ANALYSED) < 3
    ORDER BY LAST_ANALYZED DESC
  )
  LOOP
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "' || r.owner || '"."' || r.table_name || '"'
      INTO res;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(
      'details:' || r.owner || '.' || r.table_name || ': '
      || res
    );
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(
      'perfdata:' || r.owner || '.' || r.table_name
      || ': ' || res || ';' || warn || ';' || crit || ';100'
    );
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(
       'exit:'|| CASE WHEN res <= warn THEN 0 WHEN res <= crit THEN 1 ELSE 2 END
    );
  END LOOP;
END;
/


This is what worked for me:
VARIABLE res NUMBER;
def warn = 1;
def crit = 2;

prompt details:Last Analayzed Tables;

BEGIN
    SELECT max(
        CASE
            WHEN TRUNC(MONTHS_BETWEEN(TRUNC(SYSDATE), LAST_ANALYZED)) < &warn THEN 0
            WHEN TRUNC(MONTHS_BETWEEN(TRUNC(SYSDATE), LAST_ANALYZED)) >= &warn AND TRUNC(MONTHS_BETWEEN(TRUNC(SYSDATE), LAST_ANALYZED)) < &crit THEN 1
            ELSE 2
        END) DATE_CATEGORY
    INTO :res
    FROM
        DBA_TABLES
    WHERE
        OWNER IN( SELECT USERNAME
                  FROM   DBA_USERS
                  WHERE  ORACLE_MAINTAINED = 'N' )
    AND
        NUM_ROWS > 100
    ORDER BY
        LAST_ANALYZED DESC;
END;
/

SELECT 'long:Tables last analyzed:'||TABLE_NAME||' - '||OWNER||' - '||LAST_ANALYZED FROM DBA_TABLES WHERE OWNER IN( SELECT USERNAME FROM DBA_USERS WHERE  ORACLE_MAINTAINED = 'N' ) AND NUM_ROWS > 100 ORDER BY LAST_ANALYZED DESC;
SELECT 'exit:'|| CASE WHEN :res >= &warn and :res < &crit THEN 1 WHEN :res >= &crit THEN 2 ELSE 0 END FROM dual;


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
